# I keep getting the error Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) :

Tags: r, caching

Whenever I've been using R for a while I get the following error:

Error in exists(cacheKey, where = .rs.WorkingDataEnv, inherits = FALSE) :
invalid first argument
Error in assign(cacheKey, frame, .rs.CachedDataEnv) :
attempt to use zero-length variable name

Restarting R fixes it but it will come back within a couple of minutes after restart. How can I fix this?

I'd add a reproducible example but the error is triggered at a different block of code every time, and none of them have anything in common, so that would be useless.

Nothing aside from restarting R, I don't really know what else to do.

Comment: That `.rs.` part makes it seem like the error is coming not from your R code, but from the RStudio IDE. I presume you are using RStudio? What version are you using exactly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.